# How to get the size of an email in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have an app in `Laravel 5.2` that send emails, and I need to get the size of an email.

I searched on google but I only find how to get the attachment size.

*I actually need to get all email content size in kb, but without counting recipients.*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: show us what you have done..

Answer (score 0):

Right now I have the email template passed into a variable. My solution is to convert that variable to a string and then use `strlen`. Not sure if i get the real template size...what can be wrong?